# How can I add dots at the end of a number with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

Suppose that you want to show that a certain quantity has an exact value, possibly calculable with an infinite number of figures, by adding "..." at the end of the numerical value, as in

ε<sub>0</sub> = 8.854187817...×10<sup>−12</sup> F/m

or

ε<sub>0</sub> = 8.854187817...pF/m.

Trying

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{8.854187817{\ldots}}{\pico\farad\per\metre} 
\end{document}
```

yields the error

```
! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
```

A possible cumbersome solution is to write

```
\num{8.854187817}\ldots\si{\pico\farad\per\metre}
```

but this wouldn't work with numbers in scientific notation.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [previously accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370580/50910) no longer works with the current version of `siunitx`(v. 3.1.1 at the time of writing this).

The current working solution, as described in the [`siunitx` documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/siunitx/0), is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % Needed for \robustify

\begin{document}
\robustify\dots
\sisetup{input-digits = 0123456789\dots}
\qty{8.854187817\dots}{\pico\farad\per\metre} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

As discussed in the comments, the [`siunitx`](http://mirrors.vinahost.vn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) package documentation offers an option for parsing `\dots`, with `input-protect-tokens=\dots` (c.f. Table 14). Observe its use in the code below.

Here I show how you can use it if you are (1) using it locally (single-use), or (2) using it globally/ in a scoped environment.

Note that you can use this solution for both with scientific notation and without (expressing in pico, milli, giga etc. instead).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Explicit passing of options -- for local use}

    \(\varepsilon_0 = \SI[input-protect-tokens=\dots]{8.854187817\dots e-12}{\farad\per\metre}\) \par
    \(\varepsilon_0 = \SI[input-protect-tokens=\dots]{8.854187817\dots}{\pico\farad\per\metre}\)

    \medskip
    \textbf{Using SIsetup -- for global/scoped use}

    \sisetup{input-protect-tokens=\dots,scientific-notation=true}
    \(\varepsilon_0 = \SI{8.854187817\dots e-12}{\farad\per\metre}\) \par
    \(\varepsilon_0 = \SI{8.854187817\dots}{\pico\farad\per\metre}\) 

    \medskip
    \textbf{Breaking of }\texttt{scientific-notation=true} % pointed out by Steven in comments

    \SI{0.003\dots}{\farad} % Does not convert to scientific notation automatically
    v.s.
    \SI{3\dots e-3}{\farad} % Use this as a workaround for now..
\end{document}
```

[image: outputs]

---

**Note**

A final note here is the astute observation by Steven that `scientific-notation=true` is 'broken' by this. I attempt to show that in the last example in my code and output. Normally with that option set as true, typing `\SI{0.03}{}` would yield `3x10^-2` automatically. This is not the case when using with `\dots`. (Of course, this wasn't in your original question, so I shall leave this as a problem to be solved for another question, perhaps. `:-)`)

I am not aware of a perfect solution to this, but I have proposed a workaround, an inconvenience you would have to bear if you wish to have `\dots` parsed with your numbers.

PS. I'm not so sure about the spacings though - whether it is acceptable by 'professional' standards. I'll be happy if someone can chip in (just edit this answer, or post a separate answer of your own) regarding this, if this solution introduces wrong spacings between the numbers and units, for example.